# How to make my app immune to theme change?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, themes

Whenever the theme of the device is changed, two things happen:

1. The colours change
2. The activity is restarted

I don't want any of these to happen. The solutions already posted on Stack Overflow either deal with the first problem or the second one. I have already solved the first problem by deleting the night theme xml file and **Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar** instead of **DayNight**. But I am unable to solve the second problem. The solutions on Stack Overflow are about how we can change the theme without recreating the activity. But what I want is ***nothing*** to happen. My activity should not react to theme change. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can set `android:configChanges="uiMode"` in manifest. It should do it I guess.

Comment: You are a lifesaver... write it as an answer, I shall upvote and accept it.

Comment: kindly upvote my question if you feel this question and your answer will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the app `AndroidManifest.xml` where your Activity is declared. You can set `android:configChanges="uiMode"`

**For example:**

```
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="uiMode"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Yes +1 it worked. But, is there anyway it can be done programmatically?